# How to add custom flag in CMake building

Tags: c, cmake, flags

My main goal is to use a flag when building a project in command line. So I can add own flags like DEBUG or MY_FLAG.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define debug_print(format, ...) printf(format, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define debug_print(...)
#endif

int main() {
    debug_print("%s\n", "Debugging mode");

    return 0;
}
```

I build the program with:

```
cmake -H. -Bbuild
make -C build -j
```

then run with

```
./build/main
```

I added `add_definitions(-DDEBUG)` to the CMakeList file which works fine.
But I want to add the flag in the `cmake -H. -Build` process.

I tried with `cmake -H. -Build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The way I solved it was by adding this line to CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_compile_options("$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:RELEASE,MINSIZEREL,RELWITHDEBINFO>>:-DDEBUG>")
```

This way, whenever `-DMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set to either `RELEASE`, `MINSIZERE`, or `RELWITHDEBINFO`, my custom flag `DEBUG` will not be defined.